# Awesome Oscillator and Macd Combo

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to combine these two indicators into one, but I keep getting errors. I'm not sure where the mistake is or if it can be done at all. Can anyone help with this?

```
        //@version=4
study(title="AO and MACD", shorttitle="MACD +")

//AO
nLengthSlow = input(34, minval=1, title="Length Slow")
nLengthFast = input(5, minval=1, title="Length Fast")
xSMA1_hl2 = sma(hl2, nLengthFast)
xSMA2_hl2 = sma(hl2, nLengthSlow)
xSMA1_SMA2 = xSMA1_hl2 - xSMA2_hl2
```

**** cClr = xSMA1_SMA2 > xSMA1_SMA2[1] ? blue : red
   **** plot(xSMA1_SMA2, style=histogram, linewidth=1, color=cClr)

these are the errors that I'm getting...
Thanks Ken... the errors are at (****line 36) undeclared identifier 'blue' undeclared identifier red.  (****line 37) undefined identifier 'histogram' undefined identifier 'cClr' (which are the last two lines of the script.

Comment: *I keep getting errors* is not a problem description. What *errors* are you getting? You have the error messages on your screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from where we're sitting. There is no reason for you not to provide them here in  your question so that we have the information too. Please [edit] your question and be much more specific about the problem if you want us to help you. You can also add a [mre] that reproduces the issues at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Ken... the errors are at line 36 undeclared identifier 'blue'

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `color.` before a color name in Pine v4.
2. Add `plot.style_` before a plot style name.

Here is the fixed version of the script:

```
//@version=4
study(title="AO and MACD", shorttitle="MACD +")

//AO
nLengthSlow = input(34, minval=1, title="Length Slow")
nLengthFast = input(5, minval=1, title="Length Fast")
xSMA1_hl2 = sma(hl2, nLengthFast)
xSMA2_hl2 = sma(hl2, nLengthSlow)
xSMA1_SMA2 = xSMA1_hl2 - xSMA2_hl2

cClr = xSMA1_SMA2 > xSMA1_SMA2[1] ? color.blue : color.red

plot(xSMA1_SMA2, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=1, color=cClr)
```